# How to make angular 7 application compatible with microsoft edge browsers?

Tags: angular7, microsoft-edge, compatibility

We have an angular 7 application that we have been developing for a few months now.  Our application is compatible with IE, Chrome, Firefox so far, now we're testing for Microsoft edge browsers.  The application will not run in older MS Edge browsers.  The latest version of edge works fine but one of our testers is using an older version of edge that needs to be compatible with the application.  The version she is using is

Microsoft Edge 44.17763.1.0
Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.17763
@2018 Microsoft

```
***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

In our index.html file we have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>MYAPP</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there any error in console when it not run in Edge? From the [official documentation](https://v7.angular.io/guide/browser-support#mandatory-polyfills) of Angular 7, it shows that in Edge the polyfill required is ES7/reflect. And if AnimationBuilder is used, we need web animation polyfill in Edge/IE. You could check if all the polyfills have been imported correctly.